What does a crystal field mean, exactly?
I'm in grade 12 and just recently learned the nitty-gritty of coordination chemistry and compounds. In the crystal field theory in our syllabus, we study the specific case of the loss of degeneracy of transition metals in an octahedral field, but what exactly does a crystal field mean? I have searched for it everywhere and cannot find a satisfactory answer. It's not like it's a need-to-know concept, I just want to know what the title of the topic actually entails. Does "crystal field" just mean the electrostatic field between positive metal ions and the ligands, taken either as point charges or dipoles or is it something else?

I think it means pretty much that.

Maybe you find this link useful. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Crystal_Field_Theory/Crystal_Field_Theory
